# Push–Relabel Maximum Flow Algorithm $x_f(s)\leq0$

Tags: algorithms, network-flow

I'm looking at [Push–Relabel Maximum Flow Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push%E2%80%93relabel_maximum_flow_algorithm) (or Goldberg-Tarjan Algorithm) and trying to solve some homework question.

As part of the answer I'm trying to prove $x_{f}(s)\leq0$
  during the entire algorithm run (where $s$
  is the source, and $x_{f}:V\to\mathbb{R}$
  is the excess function $x_{f}\left(u\right)=\underset{v\in V}{\sum}f\left(v,u\right)$
 ).

I feel like this somehow should be trivial, but no matter what I've tried, I was unable to prove it.

I know pushes into $s$ are possible
 , just not sure how to show they don't make $x_{f}\left(s\right)>0$
 .

I assume the proof would be by induction, as at the start $x_{f}\left(s\right)\leq0$
  since the initialization step saturates all of $s$
 's adjancet nodes.

If we assume $x_{f}\left(s\right)\leq0$
 , we have to show that after one iteration of the algorithm it still holds.

- Relabel is trivial since it doesn't change the flow.
- A Push from nodes unrelated to s is trivial as well.
- A Push from s to any other node would decrease $x_{f}\left(s\right)$
  so that is trivial as well.
- I'm only left with the case $Push\left(u,s\right)$.

Help or direction would be appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: If you consider the **valid labeling** condition for $s$, you can see that $x_f(s)$ is always negative.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: $s$'s neighbours can sometimes Push back to s. They can get a label that is greater than $s$, so I'm not sure how to use that...